# Spring Data REST: path variable in base path

Tags: spring, spring-data-rest

I am trying to expose a Spring Data REST resource within an existing system.

I need to expose a "Customer" resource, which works just fine (I'm working on a Spring Boot app and the configuration was automatically picked up).

**Problem**

I'd like to prefix this new customer resource with **a base path that contains a path variable**. Spring Data REST offers an option to hardcode the base path, but doesn't recognize the path variables. I'd like to get dynamic `{companyId}` path variable to the base path:

```
spring:
  data.rest.base-path: /v1/api/{companyId}
```

^ Crashes with:

```
Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 8: /v1/api/{companyId}
```

The company isn't really an entity that would relate to customers, it's a client-supplied path variable.

Comment: Depends what you mean  by dynamic... `/v1/api/${companyId}` would pick it up from one of: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

Comment: I meant a path variable, that would correspond to `@PathVariable("companyId")` binding